# How to create a pin plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

How do you create a 'pin plot' in matplotlib, or is another library required? The code I have to plot points is below. The top plot is the output of my code, the second is the ideal output.

```
def getData(n):
    data = []
    for i in range(n):
        data.append(i)
    return data

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
n = 10
axs[0, 0].scatter([i for i in range(n)], getData(n))
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

[image: Pin Plot]

Comment: Option 1: use [vlines](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html). Option 2: very [thin bars by setting width](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html)

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll look into this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called a [`stem`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.stem.html) plot in matplotlib:

```
plt.stem(range(10), markerfmt='None', basefmt='C0-')
```

[image]

Comment: Yikes. Never seen that one before after all this time. Obviously, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just to formalize the answer to this question from [Mr. T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8881141/mr-t), my preferred solution is to use [vlines](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html), as seen in the code, which produces the image below:

```
def getData(n):
    data = []
    for i in range(n):
        data.append(i)
    return data

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
n = 10
axs[0, 0].vlines([i for i in range(n)], 0, getData(n))
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Loving your solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

What about using bar plots, but extremely thin?

```
plt.bar(x, y, width=0.01)
```

[image: Result]

You can make this even thinner, it works...

Comment: This does work, however I think that the vlines have a cleaner look for my application.

Comment: @Oliver F Bar plots can be customised to whatever you want, vlines are only different in that they are levitating. If you prefer levitating, go for vlines, if you don't prefer anything, go with what you feel easy, but don't think bar graphs can't be customised to look better, 0.03 thikness was gives the same output, except it doesn't levitate, keep that in mind before deciding what to use.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, however I do like the levitating feature.

Comment: Shambhav, you can adjust the axis offset when using vlines as well.